# How to .hide() a single div from a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of divs which are specified under the same class name, and which have no ids. Given this scenario, how can I use Jquery's `.hide()` method to hide only the div that was clicked, and not the entire class without having to specify an id for each div?

```
<div class="div"><p>Some placeholder text </p> </div>
<div class="div"><p>Some more placeholder text </p> </div>
<div class="div"><p>And even placeholder text </p> </div>


$(".div").click (function(){  
    $(".div").hide(); 
    });
```

The script above will hide all divs with the class "div" but we only want to hide the div that was clicked, not the entire class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$(".div").click (function(){  
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the element being clicked in a `jQuery` object by using `$(this)` in the event handler, like so:

```
$(".div").click (function(){  
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $(".div").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

`$(this)` will return the current invoked item. You can use that to hide

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/sz4h2/

Comment: that's exactly same as @josh answered.

Comment: I guess he wasn't fast enough. :P